# Random Questions keep on repeating

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have made a system in visual studio using asp.net(c#) where the questions are taken from database and are displayed to users.

but the questions are getting repeated and i can't figure about whats wrong with it and plus some questions are not getting displayed.

below is the relevant  C# code for it

```
public partial class Computertest : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public static SqlConnection sqlconn;
    protected string PostBackStr;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=SHAHBAAZ-PC;Initial Catalog=project;User ID=sa;Password=pass;";
        PostBackStr = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(this, "time");
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            string eventArg = Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"];
            if (eventArg == "time")
            {
                getNextQuestion();
            }
        }
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Label1.Visible = false;
        txtName.Visible = false;
        Button1.Visible = false;
        Panel1.Visible = true;
        lblName.Text = "Name : " + txtName.Text;
        int score = Convert.ToInt32(txtScore.Text);
        lblScore.Text = "Score : " + Convert.ToString(score);
        Session["counter"] = "1";
        Random rnd = new Random();
      int i = rnd.Next(1, 6);//Here specify your starting slno of question table and ending no.
        //lblQuestion.Text = i.ToString();
        getQuestion(i);

    }
    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        getNextQuestion();

    }
    public void getQuestion(int no)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=SHAHBAAZ-PC;Initial Catalog=project;User ID=sa;Password=pass;";
        string str = "select * from ComputerQuestion where slNo=" + no + "";
        SqlDataAdapter da2 = new SqlDataAdapter(str, con);
        DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();
        da2.Fill(ds2, "Question");
        if (ds2.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            DataRow dtr;
            int i = 0;
            while (i < ds2.Tables[0].Rows.Count)
            {
                dtr = ds2.Tables[0].Rows[i];
                Session["Answer"] = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(dtr["Correct"].ToString()) - 1);
                lblQuestion.Text = "Q." + Session["counter"].ToString() + "  " + dtr["Question"].ToString();
                RblOption.ClearSelection();
                RblOption.Items.Clear();
                RblOption.Items.Add(dtr["Option1"].ToString());
                RblOption.Items.Add(dtr["Option2"].ToString());
                RblOption.Items.Add(dtr["Option3"].ToString());
                RblOption.Items.Add(dtr["Option4"].ToString());
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
    public void getNextQuestion()
    {
        if (Convert.ToInt32(Session["counter"].ToString()) < 6)//10 is a counter which is used for 10 questions
        {
            if (RblOption.SelectedIndex >= 0)
            {
                if (Session["Answer"].ToString() == RblOption.SelectedIndex.ToString())
                {
                    int score = Convert.ToInt32(txtScore.Text) + 1;// 1 for mark for each question
                    txtScore.Text = score.ToString();
                    lblScore.Text = "Score : " + Convert.ToString(score);
                }
            }

            Random rnd = new Random();
            int i = rnd.Next(1, 5);
            //lblQuestion.Text = i.ToString();
            getQuestion(i);
            Session["counter"] = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(Session["counter"].ToString()) + 1);

        }
        else
        {
            Panel2.Visible = true;

        }
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated a lot .

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide your code as a [short, but complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that is included in the question instead of a pastebin link (you can use the "edit" link under your question for that). This will greatly increase the chance of people looking at your problem and helping you.

Comment: _"below is the whole C# code"_ - show the relevant portion of it here.

Comment: Dear coders, 

The issue is i am not getting any errors and i can't figure out whats wrong with the code .

Comment: Set breakpoints, step through your code, inspect your variables.

Comment: @user3184290: That's good to know. Still, please follow the advice and prepare and include an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Would you please show the current output and the expected output?

Comment: @user3184290: How often do they repeat? If it's about 1/4 ~ 1/5 it's to be expected.

Comment: Dear coders,Relevant part is mentioned now.

Comment: Note that `Random.Next(1, 6)` will never produce 6, it will produce 1-5 only, 6 is exclusive. If you have 6 questions in the database, use 7 as the exclusive max value.

Comment: Not sure but it sounds like some trouble I met recently. Try defining the random once only (outside of the method) instead of recreating it on every method call..

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen tried that , Same thing , Its getting repeated.

Comment: Also note that if you call `Random.Next` in a sequence, you have no guarantee it will cycle through all the numbers before selecting a number that has already been picked.

Comment: "ok, same thing", can you please post some more concrete data, like, how many questions do you have in the database? how often/for how long are the questions repeated, can you post some example data?

Comment: Keep the [birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) in mind -- if you have `n` questions and randomly pick from them, you will get the first repeated questions after asking about `sqrt(n)` of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi here the problem is with your random function.
If you want to make sure one question will get repeated only after all the questions have shown atleast one.

**step 1:** keep a array with length equal to the number of question.

**step 2:** get a random question .

**step 3:** check if its id present in Array.

```
        If not present 
         add   it to arrayand show the questions
        else
        get next random question repeat the check
```

**step 3:** before adding an item to array check

```
   if array full make array empty and add new question ID
```

Repeat whole steps

Comment: @user3184290 So basically there was no real problem with the *code* as such, it was with the expectation about what the word "random" means.

Comment: yes the code is working fine only. he just cofused with random function

Answer (score 0):

You're issue is to do with creating a new `Random` object every time.  You should have one instance that you call `Next` on each time.

It's due to the way its implemented and the fact that its seeds from the clock time.

See Jon Skeets article here for a good explanation and suggestions on how to resolve it: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter12/Random.aspx

It seems you may also only have 6 questions, so there will be less possibility of repeating the questions if you have more questions to choose from!  Also on the second call, you only select questions 1 to 5, which will exclude question 6 entirely if it hasn't been picked the first time.

**The solution:**

The way it currently works you do not exclude any already selected questions from being selected again, so the solution I would use is to retrieve all (or a subset) of the questions, then shuffle them.

From there, just pick them out in the order that they are then in, which will guarantee that you get a different question every time.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be on a hotpath in a loop though, I too thought that was the likely cause but judging from the places where the `Random` values are constructed, there's no loops surrounding that code. You have it in button click, and in `getNextQuestion` which is not called from a loop either.

Comment: It isn't in a tight loop, but could still be affected by the same cause.  Have you tried using just one Random instance to see if it has any effect?